# How to disable input outline in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use angular material mat-form-field and matInput. But input has this outline [image] [image]. How can i remove it?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form__item">
            <input
                matInput
                name="autocomplete"
                id="autocomplete"
                type="text"
                formControlName="city"
                placeholder="Start typing ..."
            />
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Unclear on what you really want instead, but if you don't want the outline, then do not use `appearance="outline"` like you are using now :) Options: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Comment: Oh, i want to disable outline color  changing :D